# Screen (not OS) freezes unless I move the mouse

Tags: mouse, screen, freeze, cursor

I have a Lenovo Legion laptop and an LG monitor plugged to it through HDMI. The screen image freezes until I move the mouse. It is not the system that is freezing, just the image. For instance, when writing this post, I type and nothing appears on screen. Then I move the mouse and all I have been writing appears. If I keep moving the mouse while typing, then I do see the letters showing up as I type. The same for everything else: if I have something like a progress bar for a download, or an installation, I only see the state of the progress bar if I move the mouse. Otherwise the download just seems to be stuck there, while it's not.
This does not happen on the laptop's native screen. I tried different layouts among the two screens, I even reinstalled the system, with no success.

Any idea what this might be? A compatibility problem with the monitor? Anything else?